# Get a javascript object's methods with http get request?

Tags: javascript, json, express, http, axios

> I have an object constructor in my server file that constructs an object that includes some functions. When I send the object with Express in my server.js file and retrieve it with an axios get request in my app.js file, the object's functions are missing. Why is this? How can I send/get the functions with the object?
>
> I'm using React (I don't think that matters though). The functions allow me to update the object's data. The object is supposed to act as a folder for other sites.

#### Server.js

```
const sites = []; //array that holds objects

//this function generates a random ID for the object
const makeID = function () {
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
  
//Here is my object (site constructor)
const makeSite = (customerInfo={}, parent=undefined, isMain=false, isFile=false, subsites=[]) => {
    const site = {
        customerInfo,
        isMain,
        subsites,
        isFile,
        id: makeID(),
        get title() {
            if (!this.isMain) {
            return `${parent.title}/${this.customerInfo.name}`;
            } else {
            return this.customerInfo.name;
            }
        },
        addSubsites(subsite_arr) {
            this.subsites += subsite_arr;
        }
    };
    return site;
}

//Here is a function that allows me to make a default object and add it to the array of sites
publishSite = (info) => {
    const newSite = makeSite(info, undefined, true, false); //calling constructor
    newSite.addSubsites([ //default subsites
        makeSite({name: 'Scope'}, newSite),
        makeSite({name: 'Notes'}, newSite),
        makeSite({name: 'Material'}, newSite),
        makeSite({name: 'Changes'}, newSite),
    ])
    sites.unshift(newSite);
}

publishSite({name: "RED"}); //adds object to sites array

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/sites', (req, res) => {
    res.send(sites); //sends sites array (see top of code)
});
```

#### App.js

```
//function that gets sites array and logs it to console/updates state
async refreshSites() {
    const {data} = await Axios.get('/sites');
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({sites: data})
}
```

#### When I run the app, this is logged to the console

```
[{…}]
  0:
    customerInfo: {name: "RED"}
    id: "_pppxh5zy6"
    isFile: false
    isMain: true
    subsites: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    title: "RED"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
```

> It has all the info except for the methods, and calling the methods throws an error. It's also worth noting that the 'title' property of the object never changes even when I change the objects customerInfo.name directly. How can I send the object's methods and call them in app.js (such as addSubsites)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send functions through the http protocol. If you wish to use the same constructor and methods, my tip is, move all this code to a file without any environment (nodejs, browser) references, and use the same file in both places.

Comment: Thank you! If I was to keep the code in separate file, I was thinking I could make more put/get request handlers outside of the object that could update/retrieve the object properties (such as adding subsites and getting the title) in the server.js file. Is this a good option?

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea. You should think like, the object which you will send through the http protocol should be only a simple object, without functions, just data. There are many ways to organize the code, but definitely, one thing you have to keep in your mind is separate the code by concerns. Maybe, read something like this: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/programming-fundamentals-part-5-separation-of-concerns-software-architecture-f04a900a7c50